# How to disable featured image from inside of the blog post?

Tags: images, themes

I am using Newspaper theme and what I want is to hide featured image inside blog post but to show on homepage. Can anyone get me solution to my query?

Comment: You'll need to ask the theme author for assistance with this, as the answer depends on the theme's implementation.

Comment: @JacobPeattie isn't there a way it can be done by implementing Child theme or some kind of code?

Comment: Probably, but it’s impossible to say exactly what to do without specific knowledge of the theme, and third party themes are off topic.

Answer (score 0):

The Newspaper theme by tagDiv offers options to hide the featured image from single posts directly from its theme panel. Here's how you can do it:

1. From your WordPress Dashboard, go to the "Newspaper" -> "Theme Panel" option.
2. Once you're in the theme panel, navigate to the "Post Settings" tab.
3. Here you will find an option "Show Featured Image". Simply turn this off, and it should hide the featured image on your blog posts but still display them on the homepage and archives.
4. Remember to save your changes.

This method allows you to hide the featured image globally across all the posts. If you want to hide the featured image on specific posts only, you'll have to do it manually for each post. Here's how:

1. Edit the post where you want to hide the featured image.
2. Look for the "Post Settings" box usually on the right-hand side of your post editor.
3. Under the "Featured Image" settings, you should see a checkbox for "Hide Featured Image". Check this box to hide the featured image from this post.
4. Update or publish your post.

Remember, these steps apply specifically to the Newspaper theme by tagDiv, and they might vary slightly based on the theme version you are using.

If you do not see these options, or if these options are not part of your theme setup, you may need to add custom CSS or modify the theme files to achieve this, which requires a bit more technical expertise.